# How to verify Google Analytics script on all web pages

Tags: google-analytics

I have included Google Analytics script in the footer all pages of my web sites. 
Is there any tool which can help me to verify that the script is installed properly
in all the pages of the particular domain ?

Warm Regards

Supratik

Answer (score 0):

http://www.gpablo.com/ - haven't used it myself but it looks like it will do what you want.